# lsblk command to redirect the output to csv file using shell command or shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I am running the below command and it gives the output as below.

```
lsblk -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,FSTYPE

NAME              MOUNTPOINT     SIZE FSTYPE
fd0                                4K
sda                               32G
ââsda1            /boot          500M xfs
ââsda2            /             31.5G xfs
sdb                              512G
ââsdb1            /mnt/resource  512G ext4
sdc                              128G LVM2_member
ââvgdata-lvdata   /u01           128G ext4
sdd                                1T LVM2_member
ââvgdata5-lvdata5 /ora01        1024G ext4
sde                               16T LVM2_member
ââvgdata4-lvdata4 /data           16T ext4
```

But i wanted the output as below

```
sdc,ext4,128G,
sdd,ext4,1T,
sde,ext4,16T,
```

But if the run the command,

```
lsblk -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE,SIZE | cat -vets  | sed -e "s/.*@//1" | egrep "sdc|sdd|sde" | awk '{ print $1","$2","$3","$4 }'
```

it gives the below output

```
sdc,LVM2_member,128G,
sdd,LVM2_member,1T,
sde,LVM2_member,16T,
```

Can anyone please help me to get this done.

Comment: Why do you need to combine all those different commands? `awk` can do its own pattern matching and regexp replacement.

Comment: Can you pls let me know how to do it.

Comment: Instead of `egrep XXX | awk '{...}'` use `awk '/XXX/ {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
!NF{
  next
}
{  gsub(/\r/,"")  }
/sdc|sdd|sde/{
  sub(/_.*/,"",$NF)
  print $1,prev_mount,$(NF-1)
  prev_mount=""
  next
}
{
  prev_mount=$NF
}' Input_file
```